# Log-in with two users for the same site in the same time in PHP

Tags: php

In my db users i have 2 users namely u1 & u2. when i login with u1 and open a new tab and login with u2. the u1 is automatically converted into u2. which makes me to have two tabs displaying the same content. can someone please provide me some help.

Comment: Its because You Have same Session Name. So When You are login Session is Assigned to u1 And When Login again Session Assigned to u2.

Comment: You are probably using PHP $_SESSION or at least cookies to handle authentication. The browser keep those information between tabs. If you open a "Private Mode" it won't be shared and it should behave normally. What I would suggest, if you really need this feature, is NOT using COOKIES for that. Perhaps, always send and "AUTHENTICATION" token manually putted in the header of the request.

Comment: Use a different browser. Or Firefox's container tabs (if you're on FF)

Comment: When the browser stores a session token it is shared between tabs. This means when you login as u2 after u1 u1s' session token is overridden. You can get around this by using private browsing.

Comment: @RafaelPaulino I tried private mode in chrome it does not work

Comment: @KarlGraham doesnt work

Comment: @kerbholz this works but can i understand why it doesnt in private mode

Answer (score 0):

This is not good approach, but you have to play with browser cookies and create session because if that session cookie gets changed, it will update in the browser also. Browsers do not support multiple sessions. it is possible in two different browser login with two different users normally.

Comment: It should work with private mode also, you have something wrong

Answer (score 0):

In login code, you need to validate the credentials and redirect a link which will have session id generated by you. 
Pass session id in url in every url except login. If the session id is present and valid then display that user related data.

If session id is not present in url then display login page.